# How long does it take to analyze, design and program a CMS using ASP.NET ?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm a student and I have to choose a final year project for my diploma in computer programming.

I intend to choose developing a Web Content Management System using asp.net with VB.net 2008
but I'm not sure about how long it takes to program such system.
Is 4 months enough for developing such system?
This 4 months is the duration of this semester and includes about two months for analysis and design and the rest is left for implementation.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Between 5 hours and few years. It depends on functionality, design, user friendly, etc. 4 months are absolutely enough to implement a decent cms, assuming you can program.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your first problem is going to be defining what a CMS actually is. There are many different applications that claim to be CMS, and they have wildly different capabilities. You need to identify what the core features of the CMS that you intend to build would actually be - for instance, do you intend the CMS to be modular? Do you intend it to be extensible?

Work out what features you want to incorporate, and then see if it will fit into this time frame - you're probably going to end up dropping nice-to-have features in order to fit the timescales.

What you haven't identified - which you are going to have to factor in, is how familiar you are with VB.NET and ASP.NET. If you are just learning them, you'll be able to fit less in than if you are an expert in them.

Comment: I finished a course in Visual Programming using VB.NET which includes creating Windows forms and Connecting to databases..etc.

Currently along with this project I'm taking ASP.NET with VB.NET.